# csv file parsing and making it dict

Tags: python, csv

i have a .csv file trying to make it in a dict. I tried pandas and csv.DictReader mostly but until now i can print the data (not in the way i want) with the DictReader.
So the main problem is that the file is like

```
header;data (1 column)
```

for about 50 rows and after that it changes the schema like

```
header1;header2;header3;header4
```

in row 50 and row 50+

```
data1;data2;data3;data4 etc..
```

```
with open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf-16') as f:
    for line in csv.DictReader(f): 
        print(line)
```

thats the code i have for now.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't think `DictReader` allows you to change the field names in the middle of the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `DictReader` for this, because it requires all the rows to have the same fields.

Use `csv.reader` and check the length of the row that it returns. When the length changes, treat that as a new header.

Hopefully you don't have adjacent sections of the file that have the same number of fields but different headers. It will be difficult for the script to detect when the section changes.

```
data = []
with open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf-16') as f:
    r = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';')

    # process first 52 rows in format header;data
    for _ in range(52):
        row = next(r)
        data.append({row[0]: row[1]})
    # rest of file is a header row followed by variable number of data rows
    header = next(r)
    for row in r:
        if len(row) != len(header): # new header
            header = row
            continue
        d = dict(zip(header, row))
        data.append(d)
```

Comment: yeah you are right about it, because i forgot to mention that in some rows there are more than 2 values for a header

Comment: I understood that. It starts with 2 values, then changes to 4 values after about 50 lines.

Comment: it starts with 2 values some lines has 3 values and after that it gets to 4 from line 52-252

Comment: I've changed it to be more general: whenever the number of fields changes, it's a new header.

Comment: tried it its close...trying to fix it because this way it takes as header always the the header from line 1.

Comment: for 52 lines the header is the first word of each row and the rest is the data of it
after those lines the first line has the headers and above are the data for each header

Comment: Oh, I didn't understand that part of the description. Is it guaranteed to be exactly 52 rows? The question says "about 50 rows".

Comment: yeah at start said 50 (but it was just for the case) yeah the format doesnt change in every file its 51 lines like header;data1;data2 and maybe some lines with data3
52 line is header1;header2;header3;header4 and 53-251 its data1;data;2;data3;data4

Comment: Why do you have this mixed up data all in one file?

Comment: they come from a station that measures electromagnetic and i have to make them on dict to make graphs out of it